# To set default value of 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a large 2D array like `a[100000][100000]`. I do not want to iterate and give value `0` to each block. How can I give array default value `0` at time of initialization?

Comment: memset(a, 0, sizeof a);

Comment: A general option: `std::memcpy` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy (be careful with it though)

Comment: You can also do `a[10][10] = {{0}};` or `a[10][10] = {0};` or `a[10][10] = {};`

Comment: @Caw: have you tested that? It's new to me and I hope you are right. If so, you should add it to the duplicate as answer.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) 6.7.8.21

Comment: @Caw: Unfortunately that only works for getting a default initialized value. You couldn't, for example, set all values to `1` that way, only `0`

Comment: @AndyG The question asks how to `give array default value 0 at time of initialization`, so that's fine in this case :).

Comment: @Caw: wow. I missed something past 12 years XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a[100000][100000];
std::fill((int*)a,(int*)a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(int),0);
```

Comment: this sets all the values to 0, however doesn't do it at the time of initialization as the question asked.

Comment: You only have to call it just after declaration. Or in a constructor, or in you init function.